# Encrypting Unity c# callout to node js server

Tags: c#, node.js, unity-game-engine, encryption

I have a node server and and passing up usernames and passwords from unity. here is what I have so far. I am still trying to learn and understand encryption and there are so many types and Im just confused. The code below will successfully encrypt and decrypt the string. Is this code a good code to use for something like this or is there a better alternative? What type of encryption is this actually using? How would I decrypt this on node js? Any additional example, links, or comments would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
public string encrypt(string toEncrypt) {
    CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters();

    cspParams.KeyContainerName = "ThisIsAKey";  // This is the key used to encrypt and decrypt can be anything.
    var provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);

    byte[] tempencryptedBytes = provider.Encrypt(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toEncrypt), true);
    string encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(tempencryptedBytes); // convert to base64string for storage
    Debug.Log("encrypted: " + encrypted);
    // Get the value stored in RegString and decrypt it using the key.
    return encrypted;

}

public string decrypt(string toDecrypt) {
    CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters();

    cspParams.KeyContainerName = "ThisIsAKey";  // This is the key used to encrypt and decrypt can be anything.
    var provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);
    string decrypted = System.Text.Encoding.UTF7.GetString(provider.Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(toDecrypt), true));
    Debug.Log("decrypted: " + decrypted);
    return decrypted;
}
```

**EDIT**: SHA256 code that i used added here. It doesnt output the correct string value.

```
    SHA256 sha256 = SHA256Managed.Create();
    byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("randy");
    byte[] hash = sha256.ComputeHash(bytes);

    string result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++) {
        result += String.Format("{0:x2}", i);
    }
    Debug.Log("hash: " + result);

    string result2 = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
    Debug.Log("hash: " + result2);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As a general rule, passwords shouldn't be decryptable. You should *hash* the password (using something like SHA256), then compare that to a stored *hash* in your Node.js code. **Never** store or transfer passwords plaintext or in a method that can be converted back to the original password.

In C#, hashing will look something like:

```
string toHash = "PasswordToBehashed";
SHA256 sha = new SHA256();

byte[] tempencryptedBytes = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toHash));
```

For reference, see the [SHA256 class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha256(v=vs.110).aspx) and an [example using MD5 instead of SHA256](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s02tk69a(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: A password hash, not a secure hash. You're only halfway there.

Comment: I would otherwise recommend Bcrypt but I don't know that it's included in C# without sending OP on a search for libraries. I think SHA is a suitable starting point though.

Comment: Thanks for the response and this makes sense to do on a password before encrypting it as well. But i read that using MD5 is not secure at all. I think because it is easy to "crack" but im not sure on that. This is a great additional step that I had not thought of though that I will surely implement. It does not however answer how to decrypt the fully encrypted password on the node js server.

Comment: MD5 is a different algorithm that's faster to crack, which ties in to @Maarten's comment. SHA is _more secure_ than MD5, but there are much stronger algorithms than SHA. As far as decrypting the password, you don't want to. You should have it saved encrypted on the server, and compare (encrypted == encrypted).

Comment: I've indicated a password hash in my answer.

Comment: MD5 and SHA-1 are still considered secure to hash passwords (that usually cannot contain a large amount of random data), not for hashing files or creating signatures where collision resistance is paramount. However, if anywhere possible, you should use SHA-256. Attacks only get better after all. You guys may want to read e.g. [this blog](https://blog.tjll.net/please-stop-hashing-passwords/)

Comment: I tried implementing SHA256 in Unity and i think its working but the output text value is not the same as some online generators I used to check. I tried to convert it to a string two different ways and neither worked. Any ideas why? The code is added as an edit to the original question for better formatting.

Answer (score 1):

If something is good to be used depends on the context.

If you need to pass a username / password combination then RSA encryption may indeed be used, preferably in addition to TLS transport security for the connection. If you just need to verify a username or password then you may need a password hash (or PBKDF) instead. The .NET version of PBKDF2 can be found in [this badly named class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes(v=vs.110).aspx).

Even if all the cryptographic algorithms are secure then your system may still not be secure. For instance, if you cannot *trust* the public key that you are encrypting with then you may be encrypting with a public key of an attacker.

---

So your code is using [this specific encrypt call](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f17a0e2k(v=vs.110).aspx) using a boolean to select the encryption algorithm. As the boolean is set to `true` that means that RSA with OAEP is being used, using the default SHA-1 hash function internally (which is secure for OAEP encryption, even if SHA-1 isn't). It's better to use the [newer call](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt132684(v=vs.110).aspx) where you can specify the padding without the boolean anti-pattern. In that case you can also specify the internal hash function to be used.

RSA with OAEP is specified in PKCS#1 v2.2, which is specified in turn in [RFC 8017](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017). This will even specify the byte order to be used (RSA operates on numbers in the end, which can be encoded to bytes in different ways). As long as you use a compliant library *in any runtime* and know how to encode / decode the plaintext and ciphertext (when using text) then you should be able to decrypt *using any runtime that implements RSA with OAEP*, if you have the matching private key of course.